# Detect click outside doesn't work properly on route change in a iframe on a different website

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3

I am building a web app that will be embedded inside another web page with iframe(same-origin). It uses vue-router for route change. I want to detect click outside so the user can close the app by clicking outside it.

I have this code(main.js): :

```
/* Simple click outside detector for vue3 */
const clickOutside = {
  beforeMount: (el, binding) => {
    el.clickOutsideEvent = event => {
      //Check if the click was outside the el and his children
      if (!(el == event.target || el.contains(event.target))) {
        // and if it did, call method provided in attribute value
        binding.value();
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("click", el.clickOutsideEvent);
  },
  unmounted: el => {
        document.removeEventListener("click", el.clickOutsideEvent);
      }
};
```

Usage as directive(App.vue):

```
<div id="aimy-home" v-click-outside="handleCloseClick">
    <!-- CONTENT -->

    <!-- ROUTER CONTENT -->
      <router-view />
< /div>
```

I am sorry, I couldn't make a snippet.

The code above works fine on main page. **The problem is that after route changed, even if the user clicks 'inside' the app the app will close.**

Comment: "I want to detect click outside so the user can close the app by clicking outside it." - **You can't and that's by-design**. Otherwise any content in any iframe could exfiltrate confidential user information across frame boundaries. The only exception is same-origin iframes, but you haven't said if your iframe content will always be same-origin or not.

Comment: @Dai It normally works though. But when route changed it doesn't. Iframe origin will the same. My bad.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue on a site like JSFiddle, JSBin, etc?

Comment: I tried but I couldn't as the iFrame is in another website. But I will try to add a snippet again.

Comment: I can't  reproduce an iframe web app. :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try the onBlur function on the iframe to detect when focus leaves the frame, maybe? Something like

```
<iframe 
onBlur={()=>{console.log("iframe no longer focussed")}}
> 
[your content] 
<iframe />
```